# Track memory usage process in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, memory-management, process

Powershell necessary funds to run the process, wait for it to end and print the amount of RAM that is allocated to this process.
The process runs as follows:

```
$process = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process;
$process.StartInfo.filename = "d:\tst\z1.exe";
$process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "d:\tst";
$process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true;
$process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true;
$process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false;
$process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true;
$process.Start();
if (!$process.WaitForExit(1000)) { $process.Kill(); }
//It is necessary to get the RAM
```

I tried to use $process.WorkingSet and other similar properties, but they give the wrong result.
Please, help solve the problem

Comment: Please be more specific than "give the wrong result". What are you expecting, what happens, and how does that differ from your expectation

Comment: triggered the application takes me in memory 65mb (from Task Manager). $process.WorkingSet matter ~ 1098000 (1.098 mb). In some cases (if the executable process is started and immediately terminated) "WorkingSet" set does not return anything.